# Can someone give a $f\in \mathfrak F$ such that $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in \Bbb R$ except $f(x)\equiv 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Can someone give a $f\in \mathfrak F$ such that $f(x)=0$ for some $x\in \Bbb R$ except $f(x)\equiv 0$?

Comment: $g(z)=f(z)-f(z/2), g(0) = 0$

Comment: $\dfrac{z}{b+z^4}$ for $b > |a|$.